# How to Create a smooth Scrolling Effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I saw a nice scrolling effect on this website http://www.agileinfoways.com/ and would like to know how to implement. I have never seen it before and I do not know what it is even called. The scrolling is almost mimics a `UIScrollView` on the iOS platform. Any advice on how to create this would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: One thing to try: Visit the site using firefox with firebug activated and inspect the element you are interested in.

Comment: One thing to try: Visit the site using chrome with developer activated and inspect the used scripts.

Comment: Please, don't! Javascript-based "smooth-scrolling" isn't smooth at all, and any user who has smooth scrolling enabled (e.g. mobile users, Firefox users, etc) will struggle with it, since the scroll speed is notably different. But perhaps it may be adapted, I would suggest talking with the folks over at http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Kroltan I will take that into consideration, but 98% of the traffic the website will see will not be from mobile devices. Thanks for the information, I never though that it would hinder the user experience.

Comment: @Nikita Oh well, if you have the actual data... But I know some people who literally get mad (not just frustrated) when there's a website that "reinvents the wheel". These people will definitely not like changes to what they are used to. Even if it may sound nice, consider that the user is already used to its own method or no smooth scrolling, try to only force these options when it is critical for the application's functionality.

Comment: @Kroltan Yeah, it is easy to implement many 'sugary' features that only a developer will notice, but will probably hinder the average user. It is important to find a balance and maintain a minimalist approach to design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This site using NiceScroll plugin for JQuery

Plugin GitHub page - https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll

Initialization code from site, what you gave:

```
if (jQuery().niceScroll) {
    $("html").niceScroll({
        scrollspeed: 70, 
        mousescrollstep: 38, 
        cursorwidth: 15, 
        cursorborder: 0, 
        cursorcolor: '#464646', 
        cursorborderradius: 0, 
        autohidemode: false, 
        horizrailenabled: false
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

looking at the js includes, that site is using jquery.nicescroll here's the developer site: http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/